# React Admin SelectInput in a popup

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-admin

I have the following requirement for my project using React Admin. In an edit screen, I'd like to customise the selectInput component so that it allows me to be not a drop-down list but a choice in a popup. When I click on the input I want a popup to open, and I'd like to know how I can change the value of the selectInput knowing that it comes from a component source.
The main problem is that I don't know how to change the value of the input manually so that it fits into the logic of React Admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a field value in a form goes something like this
[useFormState](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useformstate), [setValue](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/setvalue):

```
import { useFormContext } from 'react-hook-form'
import { SelectInput } from 'react-admin' 

function MySelectInput() {
  const { setValue } = useFormContext()
  const value_from_popup = ... 

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue('my_field', value_from_popup, { shouldValidate: true, shouldDirty: true })  
  }, [value_from_popup, setValue])

  return <SelectInput source="my_field" choices={ ... } />
}
```

Comment: It's ok for the choice, but the issue i have is that this selectInput is in a SimpleFormIterator and when i have two lines for example it changes all the selectInput and not juste the one i clicked on. Do you know how could i had manage this issue ?

Comment: As far as I understand, you just need to change the MySelectInput component so that the field name 'my_field' is passed to it as a parameter.